# Image Rendering features like Zoom, Rotate image using angular 6?

Tags: angular, image-manipulation

I am using angular 6 & I want display array of images in my HTML page currently I am using "ngx-image-viewer" it works fine but I want to add some image manipulation like rotating, increase brightness, Zoom In  & zoom out can someone suggest me to do better way?

```
 <ngx-image-viewer [src]="imagetoShow"
                      [(config)]="config"
                      [(index)]="imageIndexOne"
                      (customEvent)="handleEvent($event)">
    </ngx-image-viewer>
```